# SSH from EC2 to EC2, security group works with public IP, not with security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have two EC2 machines, each with their own security group (SG). One is an EC2 instance with a elastic IP. The other is part of an Elastic Beanstalk. I have my Elastic Beanstalk machine SSH to the EC2 machine using the elastic (static) IP address.

I change SG of the EC2 machine to allow port 22 from the SG of the Elastic Beanstalk. SSH does not connect.

I change the SG of the EC2 machine to allow port 22 from the private VPC range (172.31.0.0). SSH does not connect.

Is this because I'm SSH accessing the EC2 via public IP?

I change the SG of the EC2 machine to allow port 22 of the public IP of the Elastic Beanstalk. SSH connects!

How can I set up a Security group for my EC2 machine that allows SSH access from my Elastic Beanstalk instance, without relying on public IPs? (because they change when using Beanstalk I don't want to keep updating security groups).

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question!

The problem was using the public (elastic) IP of the EC2 instance when making a SSH connection. As based on [this StackoverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25490895/3018068), when using the public IP address the security group wanted a public IP address as well.

Changing the access to the public DNS (which contains the elastic/static IP address `ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com` so shouldn't change on me) allowed EC2 to resolve internal IP addresses, and thus the Security Group rule worked for another security group!